# osCommerce: custom price based on user input

Tags: oscommerce

I am writing a simple JavaScript which will update my price automatically (I know there are addons but they dont work with the nature of my products) when the user enters amount, size etc etc. I want to know how do I override the product price before/after it is sent to the shopping cart?

Example: The product price is 10€. The user select some variatons and then the price is 22,40€. I want to send that price to the checkout instead of the 10€.

So far I have written my JavaScript which updates the price based on user input and selections. I just need to know how to pass that new price variable and more important WHERE.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention "variations".  Are you using attributes?  If so, you can simply attach a price adjustment to each option value.  That would be the quickest and most proper way to handle variation-specific pricing.

Comment: I've created my own form because the pricing method is too complex to just use attribues. I've noticed $products_price in the product_info.php. Is that the variable I'm looking for?

Comment: The $products_price is the base price of the product, excluding any attributes.  If you're not using attributes at all and you have a separate product in the database for each variation, then you can use that variable.  

That being said, I've worked with osCommerce for over 12 years, and I've never found a situation where attributes were not appropriate.  The leverage provided by attributes is easy to see, once you figure in variable stock and pricing.

Comment: Can I ask you another question. Let me give an example first: User picks the amount of the product (lets say 100 pieces) and other options. Because he chose 100 pieces I need to lower the price. (lets say 10%). How can I achieve that? if(amount==100) $products_price *= 0.8; (for example)

Comment: The best way is to add a bulk discounts contribution like [Quantity Price Breaks Per Product](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/8040). You can control the quantity and levels for products on an individual basis.  Also, by using its own separate classes, it's one of the cleaner packages and a little easier to install.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and guidelines. I've accepted the answer for that:)

Comment: I have one more question. How do I add a drop down for quantity? I have a couple of select fields which now successfully updates the price. I would like a drop down which would define the quantity..any tips?